# SQL - Changing data type of an alphanumeric column

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm on Teradata. I have an ID column that looks like this:

```
23
34 
W7
007
021
90
GS8
```

I want to convert the numbers to numeric so the 007 should be 7 and 021 be 21. When a number is stored as a string, I usually do `column * 1` to convert to numeric but in this case it gives me a bad character error since there are letters in there.

How would I do this in a select statement within a query?

Comment: What's the desired numerical value of, say, `W7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that numeric values always start with a number, then something like this should work:

```
update t
     set col = (case when substr(col, 1, 1) between '0' and '9'
                     then cast(cast(col as int) as varchar(255))
                     else col
                end);
```

Or, you can forget the conversion and do:

```
update t
    set col = trim(leading '0' from col);
```

Note: both of these assume that if the first character is a digit then the whole string comprises digits.  The second assumes that the values are not all zeroes (or, more specifically, that returns the empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `TO_NUMBER(col)` which returns NULL when the cast fails.

Comment: What happens to the alphanumeric values here - does it remain as-is or does it become null?

Comment: @Moosa: Simply try it, the cast will fail and it will return NULL